# CNTK Training Speed slowing down after each epoch

Tags: cntk

I am trying to train a CNTK model directly from their language understanding tutorial.

```
Sequential([
            Embedding(emb_dim),
            OneWordWindow(),
            BatchNormalization(),
            BiRecurrence(LSTM(hidden_dim), LSTM(hidden_dim)),
            BatchNormalization(),
            Dense(num_labels)
        ])
```

Seems like the training speed slows down after each epoch (see below). Is this because of the learning rate schedule, or am I missing something here?

The LR schedule for Adam, is

```
 lr_per_sample = [0.003]*4+[0.0015]*24+[0.0003]
 lr_per_minibatch = [x * minibatch_size for x in lr_per_sample]
 lr_schedule = learning_rate_schedule(lr_per_minibatch, UnitType.minibatch, epoch_size)



Finished Epoch[1 of 1000]: [Training] loss = 0.149485 * 18059, metric = 3.46% * 18059 10.189s (1772.3 samples per second);

Finished Epoch[2 of 1000]: [Training] loss = 0.071990 * 17974, metric = 1.47% * 17974 51.836s (346.7 samples per second);

Finished Epoch[3 of 1000]: [Training] loss = 0.106882 * 17992, metric = 2.08% * 17992 60.175s (299.0 samples per second);

Finished Epoch[4 of 1000]: [Training] loss = 0.074046 * 17987, metric = 1.51% * 17987 68.655s (262.0 samples per second);

Finished Epoch[5 of 1000]: [Training] loss = 0.052539 * 17995, metric = 1.28% * 17995 77.627s (231.8 samples per second);

Finished Epoch[6 of 1000]: [Training] loss = 0.057482 * 18011, metric = 1.55% * 18011 86.191s (209.0 samples per second);
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug found in ProgreessPrinter that affects printout of the number of samples per second.  The actual speed is not affected, just the reporting of the speed is.  This bug is fixed in master -- so you can get this now, or you can wait for next formal release which is slated for 3/14/2017.

Comment: Thanks, the epochs didn't seem to actually slow down, but I was't sure what it meant.